# Point shapefile not showing up when adding layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

The layer has all the points in the attribute table and when I click `"Zoom to Layer"` it zooms to the location where the points should be, but no points are appearing.

I also have a tried uploading the points as a CSV-file which did successfully create the points. Unfortunately, they showed up in Canada and they should be in Colorado.

I checked all the coordinate systems and made sure everything was lining up as it should and still nothing.

Comment: There's a lot of reasons a layer might not show up. Can you provide more information, such as screenshots, and the coordinates of a few sample points, and info about what CRS's you're using?

Comment: If all your coordinate systems line up but your data doesn't, that means one of your CSes is *wrong*. Please [Edit] the question to specify the coordinate system(s) and envelope values for each layer.